# Stratified Sampling for XGboost

Tags: r, xgboost

I have a multiclass-classification dataset with the target (dependent) variable highly imbalanced. While using the randomForest package in R, I usually use the parameters `sampsize & strata` to account for the imbalance in training data. Are there any similar options in xgboost package also?

Summary of the number of datapoints available in each class.

Factor 1     : 667
 Factor 2     : 676
Factor 3    :7807
 Factor 4       : 850

Answer (score 1):

In R, it's an option of the cross validation function : xgb.cv
See the documentation here : https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/xgboost/versions/0.4-4/topics/xgb.cv